# How to implement end-to-end encryption using XMPP configured to archive the messages?

Tags: encryption, xmpp, archive

I am developing a app that uses XMPP. The XMPP server  (openfire) is configured to archive all messages so they can be fetched later.
We are facing a problem to decide how to implement end-to-end encryption.
We are willing to use PKI, but the client can access the chat from a mobile app and/or from a browser.
Using PKI only a specific client cand decrypt the message because the private key was generated by this specific client.

*Example:* If the user access the app from an Android device (where the keys were generated) how will the browser version decrypt the archived messages? (the same user is accessing the two versions)

Can anyone help me with that? Even a different approach is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a scheme based on OpenPGP ([RFC 4880](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt)). For XMPP this could mean using:

- [**XEP-0373**: OpenPGP for XMPP](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0373.html)
- [**XEP-0374**: OpenPGP for XMPP Instant Messaging](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0374.html).

XEP-0373 allows you to securely synchronize the secret key(s) accross devices. You can either re-use the same key across all devices of the same user, or create a key per device.

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of XEP-0373 and XEP-0374.</sup>

Comment: Nice. I'll try your solution and then I come back to say if it worked :) Thank you

Comment: Synchronizing secret keys? Then I guess those keys are no longer secret...

Comment: @Calmarius Of course the keys are protected by a passphrase, which is used to encrypt them, when being synchronized to your other devices. So you have to enter the passphrase (at least) once when bootstrapping a new device.